# Android database is locked when trying to open it

Tags: android

I am trying to open a downloaded `SQLite` `DataBase` from the Cloud and open it in `Android` but I am getting this error: `database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode`

What I've done so far is this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            api.filesDownload(mountID, "/MusicDB", DB_PATH, new SimpleProgressListener());
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException | StorageApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("DB","Eroare: "+e.getMessage());
            // CREATE TABLE'S CODE //
        }
    }
```

When I am opening the app first time I check my cloud for any database that exists and download it, untll now everything works good untill I try to open the `database`

Is there any way how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple of different problems.

- Your code looks like you are downloading the database on the UI
  thread. If you are, you shouldn't be - use a background thread. If
  you are downloading it asynchronously (i.e. on a background thread),
  then it's probably not going to have finished downloading by the
  time you try to open it in the next line of code (likely only a few
  milliseconds later).
- Take a good look at the paths that you are using to download and to open the database, and verify that they resolve to the same location. It looks to me like they may not.